# How to call Multiple icons in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, icon

I want to call my own custom icons. If I call the custom icons, default Luma icons not showing in frontend. If anyone knows please help me to get rid of this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this References :-

[Custom Icon Menu](https://store.magenest.com/blog/custom-icon-menu/)

[how-to-in-magento-2-how-to-add-custom-icons](https://zanetabaran.com/how-to-in-magento-2-how-to-add-custom-icons/)

Comment: if i call the custom font, default luma-icons not showing

Comment: Yes default magento icons are remove

Comment: but i needs to show luma icons also.

Comment: is there any other solutions plse let me know. Thanks

Comment: based on your requirement you can change icon not for all icon

Comment: i wanna show both luma and custom icons? is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: Yes using this link you can

Comment: Which link we have to use?

Comment: https://store.magenest.com/blog/custom-icon-menu/